# Proving a language is not regular using Pumping Lemma

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, pumping-lemma

So I am given the language *qr* where *q* is any combination of a's and b's. *r* is then the reverse of whatever *q* is. For example, abba is in the language because we can make a *q* = ab and *r* = ba

I have to prove, using the Pumping Lemma, that this language is **not** regular.

I can't make any sense of this, because it seems apparent that with *xyz*, we can set *x* = *z* = ε. Then we can just fit the entire expression into *y*. So for example, *y* = abba.

It doesn't matter how many times we repeat this, it will always be in the language.

- With 2 repetitions, abbaabba has *q* = abba and *r* = abba.
- With 3 repetitions, abbaabbaabba has *q* = abbaab *r* = baabba

This will always hold because since *r* is a repetition of *q*, the produced string by pumping will always be divisible by 2 in a way where the middle perfectly creates *q, r* | *r* = REVERSE(*q*)

What am I missing? Thank you for any help...

Answer (score 2):

In the case of the pumping lemma, it is not good for intuition or practice to consider specific strings, such as $abba$. The statement of the pumping lemma says that if a language $L$ is regular, then *every single* string $w \in L$ of length at least $p$ can be written as $w = xyz$ satisfying

1. $|y| \geq 1$
2. $|xy| \leq p$
3. for **every** $n \geq 0$, $xy^nz \in L$.

So your proof should go something like this: in order to derive a contradiction, assume that $L$ *is regular*. Then let $p$ be the length given by the pumping lemma. Consider the string $s = a^pb^pb^pa^p$. Now for the important part: since $s \in L$, the pumping lemma guarantees that $s$ can be partitioned into $xyz$ satisfying the conditions above. In particular, since $|xy| \leq p$ and $|y| > 0$, it must be that $y$ consists *only of* $a$'s. Thus, we can pump up (or down) and the string will no longer be in $L$.

This is a contradiction so our initial assumption (that $L$ was regular) must be false. Therefore $L$ is not regular.